Getting 12 V from original 20 V of PSU in Vintage Arcade Cabinet
I have an old Italian Arcade Cabinet which is a clone of Atari Scramble. The game name is Explorer and was made by sidam. I am in the process of adapting this pre jamma cab to jamma so to use a Raspberry Pi with a Pi2jamma board and run multiple games.
So far, I was able to make it work by making a custom cable adapter from the original connector to a jamma harness. Since the jamma needs 5 V and 12 V used an external PSU to power the Raspberry because the original PSU doesn't have 12 V, but it has 20 V in a 120 V circuit that powers the monitor.
So l had the idea to connect the 20 V to a volt reducer that supplies 0 to 3 amps and get 12 V from there, then hook it to the custom connector and also get the 5 V from the original PSU. At first, for some reason the 20 V fuse blew up as soon as the adapter was connected. Then tinkering here and there with the grounds I could make it work. The Raspberry booted, I tried some stuff on the software side, but then the 20 V fuse blew up. So l got back to the original configuration using the external PSU and leaving the original PSU alone, not using that for the raspberry but only for video and lights. What could have gone wrong? I am attaching the Explorer manual.
Ideas?
Video of the cabinet working with external PSU attached at the RP
Voltage reducer used to try using the original PSU
sidam service manual


Where is the 20V fuse in relation to the other components?  It probably is not sized for the additional load or inrush of a switching converter.

I think this post could benefit from having its text broken up a bit into sections, tbh. Right now it's hard to gather what you're asking.

Do you have any info about the level of the current drawn from the 12V rail?

@RohatKılıç I think the only component on Pi2jamma using 12v is the audio amplifier that draws at peak 1.3 amp. https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm380.pdf
Other components not using 12v but 5v I guess  are video amp https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ths7314.pdf and shift registers https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn54ls165a-sp.pdf

@vir it’s a 5amp fuse. It’s on a circuit you can see in the service manual. I’m not sure how to give the info you are asking
